# react-simple-file-upload: Attempted import error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, file-upload

I'm trying to use Heroku's new addon: react-simple-file-upload. The literature says to install "npm install react-simple-file-upload" then import it via the method below:

```
import { SimpleFileUpload } from 'react-simple-file-upload'

  <SimpleFileUpload
    apiKey="..."
    onSuccess={handleFile}
  />

  function handleFile(url){
    console.log('The URL of the file is ' + url)
  }
```

I've followed this pretty exactly but keep getting an error:

```
Attempted import error: 'SimpleFileUpload' is not exported from 'react-simple-file-upload'.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1375
```

My code looks as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { SimpleFileUpload } from 'react-simple-file-upload';

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <SimpleFileUpload
    apiKey="d0a36142ceb56a2c9295eac2feecc8ce"
    onSuccess={handleFile}
  />
    <h1 className="title is-1">Work in Progress</h1>
    <p>
      This site is a work in progress as of December 25th, 2020. 
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default About;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crappy documentation.  That is a default export.  This should do the trick.

```
import SimpleFileUpload from 'react-simple-file-upload'
```

See the code here.

https://github.com/pixelplicity/react-simple-file-upload/blob/master/src/index.js